# PHP Stand alone application Code Issue

Tags: php, obfuscation

I want to give an application in PHP to someone for usage as stand alone application. But I dont want to give the php code. Is there any possibility?

Can the installation files of PHP application be created and code be hidden from the end user?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Preventing PHP Code from being Pirated](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1698672/preventing-php-code-from-being-pirated)

Comment: @Laurent - PHP is used for other things. Like stand alone applications. Which is what the OP asked ...

Comment: I think kush is talking about a desktop application, or about giving the code to someone to use on a local server mr Laurent

Comment: Granted, it's not free, but ionCube provides a solution. http://www.ioncube.com/sa_encoder.php other than that, Joshua posted a link to a compiler for PHP in an answer.

Comment: Yes it is on the local server.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can compile the PHP code and give the executable to that person. Compiler can be found here: http://www.phpcompiler.org/